# How to remove the last UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to remove a the last uitablviewcell from a uitableview, but I am having some trouble. The code I have so far is.

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]] withRowAnimation:NO];
```

Which I thought would remove the last cell? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: the second parameter of `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is not a `BOOL`; it is a `UITableViewRowAnimation` type

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows in the section isn't 0 based (i.e. it would return 1 even though indexPath.row == 0). Try arrayWithObject:([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1).

Also, [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:] returns a NSInteger, when the array really needs an NSIndexPath object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have 1 section in your table, this should do it, depending on where you'd put this code:

```
NSInteger temprowcount = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
if (temprowcount > 0) {
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:temprowcount-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one section, assuming `self` is the view controller that contains `tableView` and conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
NSUInteger _lastSection = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
NSUInteger _lastRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:_lastSection] - 1;
NSUInteger _path[2] = {_lastSection, _lastRow};
NSIndexPath *_indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:_path length:2];
NSArray *_indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_indexPath, nil];
[_indexPath release];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:_indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];

[_indexPaths release];
```